# Why is my copy of the rhinoceros book's SVG clock a black circle?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a page, HTML at http://pastebin.com/RkhbhYra , with relevant JavaScript of:

```
var wallclock_now = new Date();
var wallclock_minute = wallclock_now.getMinutes();
var wallclock_hour = wallclock_now.getHours() % 12 + wallclock_minutes / 60;
var wallclock_minute_angle = wallclock_minute * 6;
var wallclock_hour_angle = wallclock_hour * 30;
var wallclock_minute_hand = document.getElementById('minutehand');
var wallclock_hour_hand = document.getElementById('hourhand');
wallclock_minute_hand.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + wallclock_minute_angle + ',50,50)');
wallclock_hour_hand.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + wallclock_hour_angle + ',50,50');
```

This is intended as a copy, modulo some renaming and moving to single quotes, of example 21-3 in David Flanagan's *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* (6th ed).

It doesn't seem to work; it makes a black circle with nothing nonblack inside AFAICT. The JavaScript console is not showing any errors.

I am viewing it in Chrome.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Changing #face will stop everything being black.

```
    #face
        {
        stroke-width: 3px;
        fill: none;
        }
```